# xampp error 404: object not found

Tags: apache

```
Error 404
localhost
06/21/14 11:16:38
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

I am working with xampp and joomla.... when i run my localhost in url it opens me the xampp page ....then if i try to run in url `localhost/som(directory_name)` then it gives me error

```
Object not found!
```

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

```
Error 404
localhost
06/21/14 11:34:02
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

my directory already exist...

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the .htaccess file. It might be hidden in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put an index.php OR any other file inside the directory
and access it like localhost/som(directory_name)/my_file.php because your apache
may be configured not to list directory index. Let me know if your problem still
persist.

Answer (score 0):

check joomla > global configuration > use URL rewriting, this must be set "no" in local configurations (xampp).